# how to design an inductor in Tanner L-edit and extract the designed layout in L-edit to S-edit?

Tags: layout

hello i am trying to design an inductor in L-edit.
i thought to use metal1 layer and make a squares in it for example 5 squares while there is a free hole in the center of them. actually i don't understand how it is an inductor.

second question is : when i am done with it and i use Tools-> extract and it makes T-spice code, how do i take it or the layout and use it in S-edit scheme.

i didn't find a good tutorial for that.

this is a tutorial (page 51 in the pdf), but it is not clear at all:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/72550091/29/Layout-of-Inductors

what i want to do in general is a BPF around 3GHZ.

thank

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your inductor?

Comment: i can but it is useless it the same as painting it in photoshop. i don't know how to config the ext file and make it compatible to build an inductor.

Comment: does any one know how to design and config the design of an inductor in L-edit???  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't say if this will actually help you, but you may be able to adapt the Saturn PCB Design Toolkit's planar inductor calculator to aid you in this.  Check out: http://saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit.htm.